# React component not getting rendered without a reload --using <Navigate/>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am using react 18 ,redux and react-router dom to navigate to and from pages. HOwever after successful login the screen first shows the homepage for a split second then a loader and then the screen completely goes white. But after only pressing reload manually once the Home component is rendered again. Also my Home page has a lot of nested components in its tree passing props to each other's child.

I wonder if it has something to do with the redux action dispatches?

How to make the Home page load in the first go itself?

Here is my App.js=>

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Routes , Route , Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Home from './components/Home/Home.js';
import LandingPage from './components/Landing/Landing.js'
import Login from './components/Login/Login';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { loadUser } from './Actions/UserActions';
import Account from './components/Account/Account.js'
function App() {



  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, [dispatch])
  
  const  {isAuthenticated} = useSelector(state=>state.user);

  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
      {isAuthenticated && <Header/>}
        <Routes>
          
          <Route path='/' element={!isAuthenticated? (<Navigate to='/login' replace={true} />): (<Home/>)}/>
          <Route path='/welcome' element={<LandingPage/>}/>
          <Route path='/login' element={!isAuthenticated? <Login/> :(<Navigate to='/' replace={true}/>)}/>
          <Route path='/account' element={!isAuthenticated? (<Navigate to='/' />): <Account/>}/>


        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Home component=>

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import User from '../User/User.js'
import Post from '../Post/Post.js'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllUsers, getPosts } from '../../Actions/UserActions'
import Loader from '../Loader/Loader'
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import Metadata from '../Metadata/Metadata'
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  const { loading,posts,error} = useSelector(state =>state.getPosts)
  const { usersLoading , users ,userError} =useSelector(state=>state.allUsers)
  const { error: likeError, message } = useSelector((state) => state.like);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());

    dispatch(getAllUsers());
    
  }, [dispatch])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "clearErrors" });
    }

    if (likeError) {
      dispatch({ type: "clearErrors" });
    }
    
  }, [alert, error, message, likeError, dispatch]);
  
  
  
  
  return loading===true||usersLoading===true? (
    <Loader />)
    :(
      <div className="home">
          <Metadata title='Civilised' />
        <div className="homeleft">
          {
            posts&&posts.length>0 ? posts.map((post)=>
              
            (<Post 
              key={post._id}
              postId={post._id}
              caption={post.caption}
              postImage={post.image.url}
              likes={post.likes}
              isLiked={false}
              comments={post.comments}
              ownerImage={post.owner.avatar.url}
              ownerName={post.owner.name}
              ownerId={post.owner._id} 
            />)
              ): (<Typography variant='h6'>No posts</Typography>)
        } 
          
        </div>
        <div className="homeright">
          {
            users ? users.map((user)=>(
              <User
              key={user._id}
              userId={user._id}
              name={user.name}
              avatar={'https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHlHovW8nMkFA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1610020467592?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=vBPLqLRHM1Py_hRw7vSbT86TKE7UREGqCFyvoYGyJoc'}
              //avatar={currentUser.avatar.url}
            />
            )) : null
          }
              

        </div>

      </div> )

  
}

export default Home
```

Here are the warnings I face just after a successful login when the page goes blank=>
[image]

Here are the warning I get in the console after I reload the page and the  is successfully rendered and functioning well.=>
[image]

Comment: Two things your app is fetching something which is resulting in a 401 error. And also inside of Post.js you are trying to read _id on an undefined object.

Comment: @PratikWadekar Here the `_id` AND the `isAuthenticated` state of the user is dispatched when the Home component is rendered. Because the Home page does not get rendered in the first go the actions necessary for those two objects to get dispatched in the global state is missing hence the error. On reload however the Home page gets rendered and those actions gets dispatched as you can see in the 2nd image the errors are gone , Home page gets rendered and new error pops up